# Kafka-Node not detecting kafka broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

I'm currently using Kafka-node in my application but I cant manage to connect it to the Kafka broker I have brought up before hand.

Firstly, I bring up the kafka broker with the  wurstmeister/kafka docker image. I also bring zookeeper up with the  jplock/zookeeper image. 
I thne automatically create a topic with an environment variable with the wurstmeister/kafka image. like so:

```
zookeeper:
  image: jplock/zookeeper
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  networks:
  - bitmex_backend

kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://:9092"
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "Topic1:1:1"
  networks:
  - bitmex_backend
```

I verify the container is up by listing all the topics from kafka which returns the correct number and name of topics.

I then want to bring up a producer and verify its up when I call an endpoint so I do:

```
// Import the WebFramework for routing
const Koa = require('koa')
const route = require('koa-route')
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
client = new kafka.Client(),
producer = new kafka.Producer(client);
// TODO : Generate a position/history endpoint 

module.exports = async () => {
    const app = new Koa()

// Retrive all the open positions from all the bots in the system
app.use(route.get('/open', async (ctx) => {
        producer.on('ready', function () {
            console.log('Producer is ready');
        });

        producer.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Producer is in error state');
            console.log(err);
        })

    // Response
    ctx.status = 200
    ctx.body = {
        data : "success",
    }
}))

return app
```

This code runs with out errors but no output either. Whn I check the logs the endpoint is called correctly with no console.log to prove that the endpoint has loaded.

Any ideas or pointers are very welcomed as I've been stuck with this for a while now.

Comment: What bootstrap.server parameter you set for you producer? Seems your ```KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS``` is set to localhost, this is the address your broker will advertise to your Kafka clients. This won't work if your producer is not on the same box

Comment: I have the api running on the same backend: `bitmex_backend` so it shouldnt be a worry

Comment: But your broker is running in a container which has its own loopback address ( localhost), no?

Comment: Im happy to try out any suggestions, im a bit lost as tl what an alternative would be.

Comment: This is probably a silly observation but you are not passing any configuration like kafkaHost to the client - is that deliberately omitted?

Comment: Yes,ignore me, default is what you'd expect